# Creating Multiple domains in one VPC, in Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

Is it possible to create multiple domains in single Amazon VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) created in *Amazon AWS*. ?

Comment: Rahul, don't apologize for something that is a great virtue to have on stackoverflow

Comment: I am really sorry to be so terse, I am a newbie with AWS , what I am doing is I had couple of machines setup in a VPC. I want to make two Window domains and have different set of users associated with these window domains. I created one window domain,and created a DHCP option set with that domain and dns server name. I associated that to the VPC. After that when I created a second Windows domain and tried to add a DHCP Option set for that domain to the VPC , but i could not do that. So my question, is creating two window domains allowed in a single VPC.

Answer (score 2):

The *domain-name* and *domain-name-servers* are part of an [DHCP Options Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) and a single [VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html) can only have one DHCP Option set at a time, as visible in the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) and e.g. documented for [ec2-associate-dhcp-options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-AssociateDhcpOptions.html):

> After you associate the options with the VPC, any existing instances
>   and all new instances that you launch in that VPC use the options. [...]

However, if your use case allows, you could create additional VPCs instead - by default you can create 5 VPCs per region, see [Amazon VPC Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean multiple IP's as well, the answer to this question is [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64616).

Quoting:

> You can now create and attach an additional network interface, known
>   as an elastic network interface (ENI), to any Amazon EC2 instance in
>   your VPC for a total of two network interfaces per instance. More
>   information here
>   http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/12/new-elastic-network-interfaces-in-the-virtual-private-cloud.html

Yours is a good question if for instance, you are trying to broker various web-services.